# Fast hash function for `std::vector`

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, hash

I implemented this solution for getting an hash value from `vector<T>`:

```
namespace std
{
    template<typename T>
    struct hash<vector<T>>
    {
        typedef vector<T> argument_type;
        typedef std::size_t result_type;
        result_type operator()(argument_type const& in) const
        {
            size_t size = in.size();
            size_t seed = 0;
            for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
                //Combine the hash of the current vector with the hashes of the previous ones
                hash_combine(seed, in[i]);
            return seed;
        }
    };
}

//using boost::hash_combine
template <class T>
inline void hash_combine(std::size_t& seed, T const& v)
{
    seed ^= std::hash<T>()(v) + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed << 6) + (seed >> 2);
}
```

But this solution doesn't scale at all: with a `vector<double>` of 10 millions elements it's gonna take more than 2.5 s (according to VS).

Does exists a fast hash function for this scenario?

Notice that creating an hash value from the vector reference is not a feasible solution, since the related `unordred_map` will be used in different runs and in addition two `vector<double>` with the same content but different addresses will be mapped differently (undesired behavior for this application).

Comment: Do you really use vectors of `double` with 10 millions of elements as keys? I somehow doubt that.

Comment: If so, then maybe try precalculating hash values instead of recomputing them at every key access.

Comment: @milleniumbug it's totally possible in a high load scenario with a lot RAM. Maybe he uses wrong container or should look into non-STL-solutions

Comment: This is supposed to be used for a general memoized application. So possibly yes, we can use them as key

Comment: Anyway this is benchmark phase in order to understand which map structure to use, so maybe it's not realistic, but I'm just testing the system with big keys

Comment: 1. Are you sure you're compiling with all optimizations turned on? 250ns for hashing/combining a `double` seems way too slow. 2. Check that your std library's `std::hash<double>` is not being too smart - perhaps a less fancy implementation (e.g. `*reinterpret_cast<const size_t *>(&v)` would suit your usage better.

Comment: Visual Studio at 2.5 seconds?  Did you try compiling in a Release build instead of Debug?  The results may surprise you.   If that's already the case, you'll get another huge boost in performance by just grabbing `v.data()` and iterating over the elements directly in a tight loop with your own inlined hash code. There's just too much function call overhead with 10M items as you have it.

Comment: you definitively didn't compile with optimisations, check this [ideone example](http://ideone.com/tieHbd): it takes about 50 milliseconds!

Comment: Yet another post that says something is slow, but with no indication of how the application was compiled, i.e. with or without optimizations.  If you're testing this without optimizations, these findings are meaningless.  They are meaningless since debug mode for Visual Studio adds a **ton** of iterator and bounds checking within the vector class -- it isn't just a matter of a loop unroll here or there.

Comment: Also, don't put things in namespace `std`.  Create your own namespace.

Comment: @justHelloWorld Please [see this](http://rextester.com/NWI68507).  With full optimizations, the same code takes 1/10th of a second, not 2.5 seconds.  This is why you must test with optimizations.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**NOTE:** [As](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37007307/fast-hash-function-for-stdvector/37007425#comment61567501_37007307) [per](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37007307/fast-hash-function-for-stdvector/37007425#comment61567662_37007307) [the](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37007307/fast-hash-function-for-stdvector/37007425#comment61567852_37007307) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37007307/fast-hash-function-for-stdvector/37007425#comment61569237_37007307), you get a 25-50x speed-up by compiling with optimizations. Do that, first. *Then*, if it's still too slow, see below.

---

I don't think there's much you can do. You *have* to touch all the elements, and that combination function is about as fast as it gets.

One option may be to parallelize the hash function. If you have 8 cores, you can run 8 threads to each hash 1/8th of the vector, then combine the 8 resulting values at the end. The synchronization overhead may be worth it for very large vectors.

Comment: Ok, now with the release configuration activated it takes "only" 117 ms. But if we have to do a re-hash of millions of keys (for example because of a bad load factor in the `unordered_map`) this is still an unacceptable solution. So I think that I'll try to improve it even more with your parallel solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

The approach that MSVC's old hashmap used was to sample less often.

This means that isolated changes won't show up in your hash, but the thing you are trying to avoid is reading and processing the entire 80 mb of data in order to hash your vector.  Not reading some characters is pretty unavoidable.

The second thing you should do is *not specialize `std::hash` on all `vector`s*, this may make your program ill-formed (as suggested by a defect resolution whose status I do not recall), and at the least is a bad plan (as the `std` is sure to permit itself to add hash combining and hashing of vectors).

When I write a custom hash, I usually use ADL (Koenig Lookup) to make it easy to extend.

```
namespace my_utils {
  namespace hash_impl {
    namespace details {
      namespace adl {
        template<class T>
        std::size_t hash(T const& t) {
          return std::hash<T>{}(t);
        }
      }
      template<class T>
      std::size_t hasher(T const& t) {
        using adl::hash;
        return hash(t);
      }
    }
    struct hash_tag {};
    template<class T>
    std::size_t hash(hash_tag, T const& t) {
      return details::hasher(t);
    }
    template<class T>
    std::size_t hash_combine(hash_tag, std::size_t seed, T const& t) {
      seed ^= hash(t) + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed << 6) + (seed >> 2);
    }
    template<class Container>
    std::size_t fash_hash_random_container(hash_tag, Container const& c ) {
      std::size_t size = c.size();
      std::size_t stride = 1 + size/10;
      std::size_t r = hash(hash_tag{}, size);
      for(std::size_t i = 0; i < size; i += stride) {
        r = hash_combine(hash_tag{}, r, c.data()[i])
      }
      return r;
    }
    // std specializations go here:
    template<class T, class A>
    std::size_t hash(hash_tag, std::vector<T,A> const& v) {
      return fash_hash_random_container(hash_tag{}, v);
    }
    template<class T, std::size_t N>
    std::size_t hash(hash_tag, std::array<T,N> const& a) {
      return fash_hash_random_container(hash_tag{}, a);
    }
    // etc
  }
  struct my_hasher {
    template<class T>
    std::size_t operator()(T const& t)const {
      return hash_impl::hash(hash_impl::hash_tag{}, t);
    }
  };
}
```

now `my_hasher` is a universal hasher.  It uses either hashes declared in `my_utils::hash_impl` (for `std` types), or free functions called `hash` that will hash a given type, to hash things.  Failing that, it tries to use `std::hash<T>`.  If that fails, you get a compile-time error.

Writing a free `hash` function in the namespace of the type you want to hash tends to be less annoying than having to go off and open `std` and specialize `std::hash` in my experience.

It understands vectors and arrays, recursively.  Doing tuples and pairs requires a bit more work.

It samples said vectors and arrays at about 10 times.

(Note: `hash_tag` is both a bit of a joke, and a way to force ADL and prevent having to forward-declare the `hash` specializations in the `hash_impl` namespace, because that requirement sucks.)

The price of sampling is that you could get more collisions.

---

Another approach if you have a huge amount of data is to hash them *once*, and keep track of when they are modified.  To do this approach, use a copy-on-write monad interface for your type that keeps track of if the hash is up to date.  Now a vector gets hashed once; if you modify it, the hash is discarded.

One can go futher and have a random-access hash (where it is easy to predict what happens when you edit a given value hash-wise), and mediate all access to the vector.  That is tricky.

You could also multi-thread the hashing, but I would guess that your code is probably memory-bandwidth bound, and multi-threading won't help much there.  Worth trying.

You could use a fancier structure than a flat vector (something tree like), where changes to the values bubble-up in a hash-like way to a root hash value.  This would add a lg(n) overhead to all element access.  Again, you'd have to wrap the raw data up in controls that keep the hashing up to date (or, keep track of what ranges are dirty and needs to be updated).

Finally, because you are working with 10 million elements at a time, consider moving over to a strong large-scale storage solution, like databases or what have you.  Using 80 megabyte keys in a map seems strange to me.